# use objC bridge Contacts framework in JavaScript for Automation

Tags: objective-c, javascript-automation

How do I use the ObjC bridge Contacts framework in JavaScript for Automation? I am able to use the old AddressBook framework, but not the Contacts one.

Let's say I have an ID:

```
id = Application("Contacts").myCard().id()
```

The old AddressBook framework works fine:

```
ObjC.import("AddressBook");

book = $.ABAddressBook.addressBook
person = book.recordForUniqueId(id)
console.log(person.valueForProperty($.kABFirstNameProperty).js)
```

But how to use the Contacts framework?
I tried (based on the documentation for [`unifiedContactWithIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts/cncontactstore/1403256-unifiedcontactwithidentifier?language=objc)):

```
ObjC.import('Contacts')

keysToFetch = [ $.CNContactGivenNameKey, $.CNContactFamilyNameKey ]

store = $.CNContactStore
store.unifiedContactWithIdentifierKeysToFetchError( id, keysToFetch, null )
...
```

This fails with Error -2700: Script error. The popup says `TypeError: store.unifiedContactWithIdentifierKeysToFetchError is not a function`

**Edit**: an even more basic example, the [`defaultContainerIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts/cncontactstore/1403159-defaultcontaineridentifier?language=objc) method gives an `undefined` output:

```
ObjC.import('Contacts')
store = $.CNContactStore
console.log(store)
/* [Class CNContactStore] */
console.log(store.defaultContainerIdentifier)
/* undefined */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you get an instance of the class using a class method `+addressBook`. In the second case you have no instance and you are trying to call an instance method. You cannot call instance methods on a class.

I suppose you have to create a new instance using:

```
store = $.CNContactStore.alloc.init
```